# How to fit lots of images into window area without overflow

Tags: html, css, image, algorithm

All:
**[UPDATE] I find a stupid but almost work way:**

```
function (total, W, H){
                    var fillVertical;
                    var fillHorizontal;
                    for(var n=1; n<total; n++){
                        var m = Math.floor( W/(H/n) );
                        if( (n*m>=total) && (n*m<(total+m) ) ){
                            fillVertical = {
                                row: n,
                                col: m,
                                size: +(Math.floor(100*H/n)/100).toFixed(2),
                                remainspace: H*(W-(H/n)*m)
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    for(var m=1; m<total; m++){
                        var n = Math.floor( H/(W/m) );
                        if( (n*m>=total) && (n*m<(total+m) ) ){
                            fillHorizontal = {
                                row: n,
                                col: m,
                                size: +(Math.floor(100*W/m)/100).toFixed(2),
                                remainspace: W*(H-(W/m)*n)
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if(!fillVertical){
                        return fillHorizontal;
                    }
                    if(!fillHorizontal){
                        return fillVertical;
                    }
                    return (fillVertical.remainspace<fillHorizontal.remainspace? fillVertical:fillHorizontal);
                }
```

========================================================================

If I have lots of image urls( about 100), and I put them each to an , all images are in same size(you do not need to worry the ratio issue but you need to keep this ratio, the actual size is 100 by 100).

What I am trying to do is to make images fill the window as possible as they can but no overflow, dose anyone can give me some simple algorithm to calculate the size of a single image?

Thanks

Comment: Hm, take a look at [Justified Gallery](http://miromannino.github.io/Justified-Gallery/) plugin. I think this should fit your needs.

Comment: Do you have more information for this question?
What do you have so far? (HTML, CSS, any JavaScript or the likes?)
Do you want the images to fill in a single ROW, or add up to a rectangle of images?

Comment: @RamisWachtler Thanks, I will study that. BTW, do you have any link about this based on Bootstrap or Foundation?

Comment: No, but I've used it already with Bootstrap. Worked fine for me.

Comment: @BenPhilipp I just want the most normal way, consider this as a math question, if you have 100 tiles, if you want to arrange them on a wall to take most space as possible as they can( do not worry if the wall seems ugly or not, just take as much space as you can without go beyond the boundary), what size of tile do you want ?

Comment: I see, so filling a rectangle / tiled view... Then I guess Ramis Wachtler's suggestion will work fine. I don't have any system for that up and ready, I'm sure the gallery plugin will have all you need. I just asked to make sure we all knew what you wanted exactly

Comment: @RamisWachtler Before dig into, one quick question: I read a little bit of the introduction, it seems that this plugin's purpose is to dynamically adjust the size of image to fit certain area dimension, If I want to make sure all image same size( I do not care if there is space left), can it do that?

Comment: @BenPhilipp Thanks, I am studying on that plugin see if it can fit my requirement.

Comment: You can only set a fixed height for each image. [Plugin Options](http://miromannino.github.io/Justified-Gallery/getting-started/#rowheight)

Comment: @RamisWachtler Oh, no. That is too bad! ToT , but this plugin still very very useful, I will see if I can modify some to fit my need. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt at a pure math answer.

Assuming all images are ratio 1:1, and they should scale no larger than `100px`, but still fill the full amount of space available.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k4vn2evr/1/)**

Comment: Thanks,  but sorry, I did not quite catch your idea. Wat I wanna do is make sure all images can be resized to certain proper size to fill an area "as mush as they can". In your code, it seems that it calculates the ratio to resize according to width, but how do you handle the height part, it alse need to fill an area "as mush as they can"(you do not need to limit image size to 100 by 100, any size is ok as long as they fill the most space of that area)?